# Bootstrap : Is there a relatively simple way to make my pages workable on mobile?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on my first "handmade" (i.e. not WordPress) site. Building it with Django/Python and Bootstrap 4. Even though I wrote in the contract that I am not obligated to make the site mobile friendly, the client is demanding that it work on mobile (client... amirite?).

I am looking for some fairly simple ways to make the site work better on mobile.

I am going to focus on one page, our login screen. It's kind of hard to describe, so I am including a few screenshots to show you what happens as the viewport gets smaller.

[image: Full size - looks fine]

[image: As screen starts to get smaller, login form begins to be pushed too far underneath the navbar to be seen.]

[image: Once the viewport is very small, it is not possible to access the login form at all.]

So... I feel that there's a solution to be had between (1) making the top navbar switch to a mobile-style navbar at some break point and (2) programming it to preserve the padding at the top of the main div, so that the navbar "pushes the content down" rather than covers it over.

Can you help?

Here is the pertinent code:

```css
/*navbar:*/
.brand {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h5.brand {
 color: #e3f2fd;
 font-family: "Arial";
}

.navbar {
 background-color: #2c3b4b;
}

a.nav-link {
 color: white;
}

a.active {
 color: #808080;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav li a:hover {
 color: #808080;
}

/*Main container*/

.container-fluid {
 background-color: #fffef7;
 padding: 0;
}

/*Form:*/
#form-container h3 {
 color: black;
}

#form-container {
 padding: 30px;
   max-width: 350px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #fffef7;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border-radius: 4px;
   box-shadow: 8px 8px 5px #36454f;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.panel-heading {
 text-align: center;
}

.panel-default {
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.login-links {
 padding-top: 20px;
}

.login-links a {
 font-size: 16px;
}

.btn-reg {
 margin-top: 40px;
}

/*Footer:*/
footer {
 background-color: #2c3b4b;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.footer-row {
 margin: 0;
}

#footer-container {
 padding: 0;
}

.container2 {
 text-align: center;
}

.container2 p {
 color: white;
}

.container1 h5 {
 color: white;
}

.container1 h4 {
 color: white;
}

.container1 p {
 color: white;
}

.footer-links li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    /*border-bottom: 6px solid white;*/
}

.footer-links li a h5:hover {
    color: #808080;
    /*border-bottom: 3px solid white;*/
}
```

```html
{% extends 'public_base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block load_css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{% static "css/login.css" %}'>
{% endblock %}


{% block header %}
    <div class="container-fluid" id="navbar-container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top">

            <!-- Logo -->
            <a class="navbar-brand"><h5 class="brand">Houston Chamber Music Network</h5></a>

            <!-- Navbar links -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'public:welcome' %}">WELCOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'public:new_member' %}">REGISTER AS MEMBER</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'public:new_coach' %}">REGISTER AS COACH</a>
                </li>
                <!-- <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'public:new_patron' %}">SIGN UP FOR E-NEWSLETTER</a>
                </li> -->
            </ul>

            <!-- Navbar right -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <!-- Link to external login: -->
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="">LOGIN</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
{% endblock %}


{% block main_content %}
    <div class="container-fluid" id="main-container">
        <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src='{% static "images/login.jpg" %}' alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <!-- <div class="container-fluid" id="form-container">
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <form role="form" action="" method="POST">
                                    <h1>Login form</h1>
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"></input>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></input>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Login</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div> -->

                        <div class="login-form-container">

                            <form role="form" action="{% url 'users:login_handler' %}" id="form-container" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <h3>MEMBER LOG IN</h3><br>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <img class="col-md-8" src='{% static "images/divider9.png" %}' alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email" value="{{ old_data.email }}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" class="btn btn-reg btn-info btn-block">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="login-links">
                                            <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            
                        <!-- End login-form-container div: -->
                        </div>

                    <!-- End div for carousel caption: -->
                    </div>
           
            
            <!-- End div for carousel inner: -->
            </div>
        <!-- End div for carousel: -->
        </div>
    <!-- End div for main container: -->
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Regarding question 1, you could look at the Navbar togglers in the bootstrap documentation [Bootstrap navbar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors). With the toggler you can easily create a hamburger menu.

Comment: One quick observation:  make your page more responsive by getting rid of all the absolute units (e.g. "px") and using only relative units (e.g. "%" and "em").

Comment: A further question... Is there no way to tell the browser to keep the navbar and footer separate from the main container? So that the navbar and footer don't cover the main material? That would seem like a really easy solution, if it's possible - would render the "hamburger" navbar unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The grid manager should do most of the work for you if not I use media queries where there are options for the different orientations that a cell phone would provide.

here is an example:

```
@media screen only and (max_width: 350px), (orientation: portrait or landscape) {
 #Your ID or tag {

  }
}
```

The grid managers should provide most of the functionality to getting your layout in the right place. If this does not work also try specifying more column sizes.

```
class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6"
```

I understand that if you just specify the medium column size that it could make the element responsive but being more specific with what you want to do with your layout at specific pixels sizes can make all the difference.

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 1):

As Braiden said, using the col classes from the Bootstrap library will help you.

A basic rundown and layout would look something like this

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="col-md-6>Some html in here perhaps a form</div>
    <div class="col-md-6>Some other html in here</div>
</div>
```

Essentially each row div consists of 12 columns. 2 col-md-6 will result in a 50/50 split of 2 divs within the parent row. col-sm col-md col-lg etc have different defining characteristics for sizing as it pertains to padding and height etc. You will still need to create your own hamburger menu using a similar css layout as provided in the answer above (@media) as well as font sizes and paddings, but overall the row col setup should help with keeping things together as far as mobile layouts go